# Passing values to Views... why not just extract $GLOBALS?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm wondering why all frameworks pass data to Views by an array, usually called $data and extract its contents when rendering.

Is there a real benefit for that or they're just a bunch of intelligent fools?

Note: Preventing the company designer from hacking isn't a good reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you'd risk polluting the global namespace, overwriting previously-declared variables with unexpected values and causing all kinds of trouble.  It also makes it much less clear where the values came from, the upshot of which is the source becomes less easy to follow, less easy to understand, and more importantly less easy to maintain and update.

Comment: See: Don't copy variables for no reason section: http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html

Comment: I'll accept this solution since people seems to like it but I'm not convinced.

Answer (score 0):

There are many technical reasons to avoid global variables. But the most important one is that **Every time that PHP coders use $GLOBALS a kitten dies**.

Comment: I know, that's why there's no $**_**GLOBALS in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I agree pollution of global space is the core issue.

Comment: If you post a form everything will go inside the $_POST array. Nothing can be overwritten outside the $_POST array. $GLOBALS is not $_POST or $_GET.

Comment: You can call extract() on $_POST, $_GET, or $_GLOBALS, it will overwrite a variable of the same name already declared in global scope.  Take a look at the http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php and be sure to read down the page a the numerous warnings in big red boxes about the security issues.  Generally, when the php documentation indicates that you should not use something, like extract() on user-supplied information (like: $_GET, $_POST, $_GLOBALS), I take their advice :)

Comment: Who said anything about extracting $_POST or $_GET?

Comment: Doh... excuse the brain pause... I was mistakenly thinking of the registered global arrays, not the $_GLOBAL array.  I agree, with the earlier answer pollution of namespace is the primary issue and will edit my answer.